# A simple solution to fixed Bar and max-width?

Tags: javascript, css, navigation, fixed, fixed-header-tables

I was having some problems with a fixed bar and max-width.

I came up with the solution using JS (even though sometimes on loads, the fixed Bar kind of that 'flickers') but I want a more simple solution, just with CSS.

Can you guys help me with that flicker? Can I do this without JS?

```
CSS: 
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 25px;
}
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
.navBar {
    position: fixed; 
    width: 80%; 
    border: 2px solid gray;
    height: 50px;
    top: 100px;
    left: 10%;
}
.contentContainer {
    border: 2px solid green; 
    height: 3000px; 
    width: 80%; 
    margin: 150px auto;
    /* max-width: 900px; */
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .contentContainer {
        width: 900px;
        margin: 150px auto;
    }
    #navBar {
        width: 900px;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
    .contentContainer {
        width: 90%;
    }
    .navBar {
        width: 90%;
        left: 5%;
    }
}


HTML: 
<body  onresize="myFunction()"  onload="myFunction()">
<div class="navBar" id="navBar">
    navBar
</div>
<div class="contentContainer" 
id="contentContainer">
    Content Container
</div>

JS: 
function myFunction() {

var w = window.innerWidth;
var test = ((w - 900) / 2) - 8; 
test = test + "px";
var navBarWidth = y.offsetWidth; 

    if (navBarWidth == 900) {
        y.style.left = test;
    }
    if((w >= 600) || (w <= 992)) {
        var barWidth = y.offsetWidth; 
        var test = ((w - barWidth) / 2) - 8; 
    test = test + "px";
        y.style.left = test;
    }
}
```